# What to do if a bank doesn't admit it leaked millions of customer's data

Tags: exploit, vulnerability

I found a breach on a bank's website a few months ago which exposed customer data including: SSNs, account numbers, account balances, physical addresses, payment history, tax forms, temporary login credentials (from forgot password emails), etc... Basically, everything that they had was completely open to the public with zero authentication needed. The documents went back more than 10 years and included millions of people.

I notified them, and they fixed it within 2 days. They called me and asked me to delete everything I had downloaded, and that was it.... They didn't notify their customers or anyone. I'm a customer and I'm upset. I contacted a lawyer, but he said that unless there's proof of monetary damages that there's nothing to do.

I don't have any social media presence, so posting on twitter or youtube to zero people probably won't do anything. Also, I don't want to spend a ton of time on this. What's the quickest and easiest way to say get revenge for trying to cover this up?

Comment: If there is no tag for what your question is about, that's a big clue that the question isn't a good fit here. This simply isn't a security question and you've used irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, technically speaking, you found a [vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)) and you [exploited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)) it, gaining (unauthorized) access to the data. In other words, there was a [data breach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_breach), and *the perpetrator was you*.

An important question is: did you have *permission* to look for (and exploit) the vulnerability?

Aside from that, I understand that you are upset but before going on a campaign to expose the fact, there are a few things to take into account:

- are you sure that you were not the first one to have found the vulnerability?
- are you sure that they did not investigate the incident (that *you were the cause of*) and they found out that no data leakage has ever took place? Keep in mind that as a bank, they are required by law and/or international policies to have extra measures in place to protect against data leakage (e.g. a [DLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_loss_prevention_software) solution)
- are you sure that since the lawyer told you there's not much you can do, if you pursue an action against the bank you won't get into trouble?

What you *may* do though, depending on your location and the respective legislation, is that you may ask for confirmation from the bank that your personal data have not been leaked. But before you do anything, please seek advice from a lawyer (I am not one and my suggestion above does not constitute legal advice).

Comment: If there was a legal question, this might be better on Law.SE, but that's not what is being asked.

Comment: hm, fair enough. Amended my answer @schroeder

Comment: @Spyros I didn't have permission, but the vulnerability was very obvious, they were keeping all of their documents completely public, I downloaded my monthly statement and the url say ?statement=1234, so I just tried it with ?statement=1233 and it gave me someone else's statement, this was repeatable for all of their customers. YES, I was the first one to find it, because once I called and reported it, they took down their entire website, and then put it back up patched the next day. Due to the completely public nature of the vulnerability, I don't think they have a way to determine the scope